# How to use JQuery in a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Been using JS and css, but for animation I figured JQuery would be better. 
So the code is

```
<div class="button" id="button1" onclick="function1()">
<script>
    function function1(){
        var e = document.getElementById("front_page_blur");
        if(e.style.animationName !== "slide") {                              
            e.setAttribute("style", "position:relative;");           
            e.style.animationName = "slide"; 
            e.style.animationDuration = "1s";
            $("function1").click(function(){   // this code is the problem, I want "button1_animation" to fade in. 
                $("#button1_animation").fadeIn(3000);
            }
            document.getElementById("button1_animation").setAttribute("style", "display:block;");
        } else {                                                       
            e.style.animationName = "back";
            e.style.animationDuration = "1s";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Everything works fine except the Jquery code, I want the "button1_animation" to fade in instead of just being displayed. I would post the whole code, but it would take a lot of space and this is the only problem. How do i get it to fade in instead of just being displayed?

Comment: You don't need jquery - just use html5 transition on opacity and change opacity from 0 to 1.

Comment: Put only `$("#button1_animation").fadeIn(3000);` in function. Remove the handler

Comment: @Tushar Thanks, I did just that and it worked :)